# How to setup custom error messages for my php application?

Tags: php

I want to make an application in php where users can run their php files. In that application I want to show more simple error messages to the user. Is there any procedure in php to edit default error messages?

Comment: Are you positively sure you want to let users to run a PHP code?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Yes for learning purpose only.

Comment: Who is supposed to learn? You are or your users?

Comment: well well. I'm afraid your precious configuration will be broken in minutes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to intercept errors and exceptions so you can display your own messages

Comment: Yeah. Just write all these thousands own messages. Easy-peasy

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).